# Form seems not to work anymore - not sending mails either

Tags: php, html, forms, phpmailer

a friend of mine has a side business and an associated website. the person who always took care of his website is no longer working with him and since he has 0.0 clue about all this, he has turned to me. I've been looking for the problem for 1 1/2 days now and can't find it.

At the bottom of the page is a small form to enter contact information and receive a mail. however, clicking on the "submit" button no longer displays a confirmation, nor does it send a mail via phpmailer. the page is reloaded afterwards, but the input is still there. That captcha seems not to do anything too, because the form has the same behavior with or without the captcha.

[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9x6m.png)

This is the script for the mails.

```
<?php
    
/**
* Get Template Text 
*/
function getTemplateText($text, $center = false) {
    $html = '<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnTextBlock" style="min-width:100%;">';
        $html .= '<tr>';
            $html .= '<td class="mcnTextContent" style="padding-bottom: 15px;'.($center ? ' text-align:center;' : '').'">'.$text.'</td>';
        $html .= '</tr>';
    $html .= '</table>';
    
    return $html;
}

$isMailError = false;
if(isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['email'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
        //your site secret key
        $secret = 'secret';
        //get verify response data
        $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
        $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);
        if($responseData->success) {
            require_once('../_mailer/class.phpmailer.php');
            $mailer = new PHPMailer;
            
            $mailer->IsSMTP(); //per SMTP verschicken
            $mailer->Host     = SMTP_SERVER; //SMTP-Server
            $mailer->SMTPAuth = true; //SMTP mit Authentifizierung benutzen
            $mailer->Username = SMTP_USER; //SMTP-Benutzername
            $mailer->Password = SMTP_PASSWORD; //SMTP-Passwort
        
            $mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';
            
            $mailer->FromName = NOREPLY_MAIL_NAME;
            $mailer->From = NOREPLY_MAIL;
            $mailer->Sender = NOREPLY_MAIL;
            
            //$mailer->WordWrap = 50;
            $mailer->IsHTML(true);
            
            $data = array(
                'company' => '',
                'name' => '',
                'email' => '',
                'phone' => '',
                'message' => '',
                'page_uri' => ''
            );
            
            foreach($_POST as $i => $v) {
                if(isset($data[$i])) {
                    $data[$i] = $v;
                }
            }
            $data['message'] = nl2br($data['message']);
            
            $mailer->AddAddress(CONTACT_MAIL); //Add a recipient
            $mailer->Subject = 'SUBJECT changed';
            $msg = '<p>Vielen Dank für Ihre Anfrage, wir werden uns in kürze bei Ihnen melden.</p>';
            $msg .= '<p><strong>Ihre Anfrage im Detail:</strong></p>';
            $msg .= '<p>';
                $msg .= '<strong>Firma:</strong> '.$data['company'].'<br/>';
                $msg .= '<strong>Name:</strong> '.$data['name'].'<br/>';
                $msg .= '<strong>E-Mail:</strong> '.$data['email'].'<br/>';
                $msg .= '<strong>Telefon:</strong> '.$data['phone'].'<br/>';
                $msg .= '<strong>Nachricht:</strong><br/>'.$data['message'].'</p>';
                
            $mailer->Body = getTemplateText($msg.'<strong>Seite:</strong> '.$data['page_uri'].'</p>');
            $mail_send = $mailer->Send() ? true : false;
            $mailer->clearAllRecipients();
            $mailer->Body = getTemplateText($msg);
            $mailer->Subject = 'subject changed';
            $mailer->AddAddress($data['email']); //Add a recipient
            $mail_send = $mailer->Send() ? true : false;
            
            $_POST = array();
            echo '<div id="anfrage_success"></div>';
        } else {
            $isMailError = true;
        }
    } else {
        $isMailError = true;
    }
}
```

I just dont know what to do anymore. Has anyone an idea why it seems to stoped working? We did not change anything.

Here are the last error logs I was able to get from the webhosting:

```
[Thu Sep 22 01:00:23 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 11739] [client [host AH01909: ****.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Sep 22 16:02:48 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 11739] [client [host ****: ****:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Sep 22 16:04:34 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 11739] [client [host ****: ****:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Sep 22 16:04:59 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 11739] [client [host ****: ****.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Sep 22 18:06:40 2022] [autoindex:error] [pid 23089] [client ****] [host ****.server-he.de] ****: Cannot serve directory /is/htdocs/****_E1ZMITARW2/www/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.htm,index.shtml,index.php,index.php5,index.wml,index.xml) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

Comment: One key thing - you’re using a very old version of PHPMailer, so if your PHP version has been updated, it may have broken it. Also, if you are sending through gmail, they changed their authentication recently, and that’s like to break your form too.

Comment: I tried to use a newer version of phpmailer locally, but it doenst changed anything. But since I'm not 100% sure what I am doing, that could still be the problem. He's using the smtp of his webmailer at host europe, so it is not gmail.

Comment: "*the page is reloaded afterwards, but the input is still there*" - this sounds like some kind of validation is failing, maybe? Like the CAPTHA failing ... it looks like there is more to the PHP than we can see, eg is `$isMailError` used somewhere?  Is this code at the top of the page that displays the form itself?

Comment: Hey @Don'tPanic, that could be right, because like I said the page seems not to care about the captcha and has the same reaction with or without the captcha. $isMailError is used in the form as fas as I can tell. eg = <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="required" placeholder="Vorname/Nachname" value="<?php echo ($isMailError && isset($_POST['name']) ? htmlentities($_POST['name']) : ''); ?>" />

Comment: So it sounds like the form is posting to the same page the form is displayed on, and this PHP code is at the top of that page. The code in your comment will display the previously entered `name`, if `$$isMailError` is true.  But in the code in your question, there are only a few ways that can happen: 1) If the form was not POSTed (check the `method` in the `<form>` tag); 2) if there is no `email` field on the form (I mean there is no input field named `email` in the HTML); 3) if the CAPTCHA wasn't included.

Comment: The CAPTCHA stuff is probably generated with Javascript, if the JS is failing, that could explain those fields being missing.  Does your browser's devtools show any JS errors on the console?

Answer (score 0):

Vielen Dank für Ihre Anfrage.

Please do not share your reCAPTCHA secret key!

**EDIT:**

You will need to reset and update the reCAPTCHA keys since the secret key was posted publicly here.

I would suggest that if nothing has changed recently in that particular form template and it suddenly stopped working (but the reCAPTCHA still validates) then there is likely an issue higher up in system.

First let's rule out the alternative - that it's a problem in the browser: [open your developer console](https://appuals.com/open-browser-console/) in your browser and see whether there is an error either when the form loads or when you submit the form. If so, edit your question to include the error.

If there's no error, you'll want to take a look next in the PHP logs. Do you have access to the hosting solution where the form is hosted? I would assume so, since you have the PHP.

**EDIT 2:**

If you can't find your PHP logs in the control panel for the hosting, please create a file on the server with:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

and then run it in the browser to see where your log is.

Then please review the log entries from exactly the moment you send the form and record the output here. Obviously you should obfuscate any information like email addresses, host names, passwords, etc.

Comment: Thank you, I edited the post. Im kinda new to all this.

Comment: Kein Stress. I am updating my answer with a more helpful solution

Comment: Everytime i releoad the page I get this in the chrome console: "reload.js:22 WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:5500//ws' failed: 
init @ reload.js:22
(anonymous) @ reload.js:65"
reload.js:22 =  socket = new WebSocket(address);
reload.js:65" = init(data);

Und ja, ich habe Zugriff auf das Hosting. Ich glaube aber, es werden keine Logs geschrieben.

Comment: @dockie I don't really understand why a PHP form which looks like that would even involve a WebSocket connection (it could be something else on the page, like a live chat?)

What kind of hosting is it? Do you have a control panel? You should be able to find the logs there. Alternatively run <?php phpinfo(); ?> and see where PHP logs are stored on your hosting

Comment: @dockie submit the form and have a look in the PHP log to see exactly what happens the instant you submit the form

Comment: Its a really simple page. Mostly text and a few pictures. no chat no nothing. It is hosted a Host Europe and I don't have access to a control panel. I can find some error logs tho. I updated my post to add them.

Comment: @dockie I have read that log entry and it looks like your web server is Apache with a bit of XAMPP somewhere maybe. Is there a new log entry when you try to submit the form? Note that you might be looking at the wrong log - inspect the Apache2 log as well

Comment: @dockie what we want is any info (errors or otherwise) from right when you submit the form (on the live site)

Comment: After submiting the form the log stays at 4 rows. I just asked my friend if he has the login data for the control panal because everything I can do now is to click on a link with the last 10 error logs. And thats it. It really looks like I cannot do aynthing to help him out. pretty frustrating.

Comment: I just opened the log.php in the browser, after putting it on the server. where can I find the location of the logs now?

Comment: @dockie Sorry to hear. I am going to bed as it's quite late here in sunny, downtown Australia. Please update the question if you have more info and I will check again in a few hours. As much as I would love to help (and improve my SO rep), if it's really taking you days to debug then it is something you could engage a qualified freelancer to easily fix on the live site for 10-30EUR, assuming it's not a security-critical application for the site owner. Once again, please be sure to reset the reCAPTCHA keys as the secret key is now recorded in the edit history for your question. Your friend, ACJ

Comment: @dockie if you mean the file with phpinfo(), you need to execute it. This can most easily be done in the browser if you put it in the domain's public folder. As best practice it should be deleted once you're done.

Comment: @dockie to clarify, if you've opened the PHP Info file in the browser, go down to the logs part and figure out where they're stored. Then read them (from the file manager, hopefully, as the easiest way)

Comment: Thanks alot! I just executed it and now i have a open site with alot o information about php and apache. But it does not tell me where the logs are located at.

Comment: @dockie search in the page for error_log (PHP, which I think you already have) and APACHE_LOG_DIR (Apache) which should give you some clues about the log locations

Comment: Apache = APACHE_LOG_DIR  /var/log/apache2.
PHP = error_log no value

Comment: Concerning that there is no PHP log. I hope this is not against the SO rules, but this is really outside the domain of a question to the community and more in the realm of regular tech support if you don't find a solution in like 8hrs then my first name is Angus and my last name is Cornwell. If you put an @ symbol in between those and then add the ccTLD for Iceland (Island) to the end, .is, you can get in touch

Comment: And it's 3am in Sydney so I am fr going to bed. Good luck!

Comment: @dockie did you solve your problem?

Comment: Hey @ACJ, not yet. The siteowner is trying to get me access to the control panel. I thought it would be a waste of time to dig deeper before that. I'm very thankful for your offer and will get in touch with you in the next days if this is alrigt?

Comment: @dockie of course :)

Answer (score 0):

if you can't get to the logs, try turning on error reporting at the top of the page:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

and set it to `exit();` before the page redirect, so that you can look at any errors in the browser without it redirecting the page.

if that doesn't display anything, try testing each suspected failure point. for instance, put an echo after the captcha check to see if it is passing. then put the entire php mailer code into a try/catch block, to catch any exceptions and print them to the browser.

```
try {
  $mail->AddReplyTo('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
  $mail->AddAddress('whoto@otherdomain.com', 'John Doe');
  $mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
  $mail->AddReplyTo('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
  $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), advanced';
  $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!'; // optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically
  $mail->MsgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'));
  $mail->AddAttachment('images/phpmailer.gif');      // attachment
  $mail->AddAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.gif'); // attachment
  $mail->Send();
  echo "Message Sent OK\n";
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}
```

make sure to turn off error reporting etc after you figure out the issue. phpMailer stuff should always be in a try catch block, so it can fail gracefully anyways if it can't connect to SMTP or whatever. original coder dropped the ball on this.

my guess is it has something to do with connecting to SMTP or authenticating that email/password to send the mail.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try this tomorrow. Really sucks that the orginal coder won't respond to anything and just left my friend alone.